# New computer build, monitor not receiving signal

Tags: computer-building

We just recently built a new computer, and have the following problem: When we turn the computer on, the LEDs and fans all function normally, but the monitor does not receive signal. We've tried using the graphics card, removing the graphics card and using the onboard graphics, attempting to reset the BIOS even though we don't see the BIOS come up, removing other peripherals, testing the RAM, and checking the CPU. I'd really like some help!

Edit: Our buzzer, when attached, gives no audio output (absolutely no beeps or buzzes) even when we remove something crucial like the RAM or hard drive

Our build:

-X740 Gaming Plus Max motherboard

-Ryzen 5 5600x

-Radeon Graphics Card with HDMI connection to monitor (Taken from a different system)

-Aresgame ACV500

-HP Monitor

Comment: Is the monitor connector to the Graphic Card output, or the motherboard output? The CPU you mentioned does not have any integrated graphic so you cannot use the motherboard output.

Comment: @Darius We tried connecting it to the graphics card, but nothing happened there either. We might not have the driver for the graphics card. How do we set up the driver when we can't get any graphics?

Comment: On the BIOS screen (before even goes to the OS) - it usually already shows some images or even the bios screen. You don't need driver for it. Have you checked the monitor input? Some monitor you have to set the i out manually (VGA / DVI / HDMI etc) as they can't do auto detection. If one type does not work - have you tried different cable? Also if you remove the Graphic Card - any beep code? (To see if you get a working motherboard that will tell you of any error).

Comment: @Darius Our motherboard does not seem to have a built-in speaker, but we have attached a buzzer in the correct socket and received no audio output. The monitor input seems to be working fine (we're using an HDMI connection) and has automatic input switching.